# Creating a tree using a relationship of Strings and Doubles

Tags: java, tree

I currently am working on a program that takes a list of Strings (names) and a list of doubles that act as distances in java. I was given a class of relationships which is:

```
public class Relationships {

private List<String> residents;
private Map<String, Map<String, Double>> distances;

public Relationships(List<String> residents, double[][] distances) {
    this.residents = Collections.unmodifiableList(residents);
    this.distances = new HashMap<>();
    for(int x = 0; x < this.residents.size(); x += 1) {
        Map<String, Double> toMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(int y = 0; y < this.residents.size(); y += 1) {
            toMap.put(this.residents.get(y), distances[x][y]);
        }
        this.distances.put(this.residents.get(x), toMap);
    }
}

public List<String> residents() {
    return residents;
}

public double distance(String rs, String re) {
    return distances.get(rs).get(re);
}
}
```

The purpose of this program is to create a tree based off the names and their corresponding distances. The first name given will be the root and it will search for the next person who has the closest distance to them and make them their child. In the next step of the process, the first person will again look for a name that is near them, but the newly created child will also look for a name that is close to them. If the distances between the root and the new child are equal to the latest search, the node that inherits that name as their child is the one who has their name come first alphabetically, for example if John and Bob are of equal distance of James, Bob will get James as his next child in the tree. An example of how the lists are set up is below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> residents = Arrays.asList(
        "James", "Bob", "Aaron", "King"
    );

    double[][] distances = {
        {0.0, 4.5, 0.5, 5.0},
        {2.5, 0.0, 2.5, 3.5},
        {0.5, 3.5, 0.0, 3.0},
        {1.0, 2.5, 1.0, 0.0}
    };

    Relationships rel = new Relationships(residents, distances);
```

Since this tree will not be binary I cannot use left and right child. How do I create the tree using those inputs. The purpose of this tree to print out traversals and the inputs during testing will be unknown. This is the method I have created to house the tree creation code.

```
public static RelationTree createModel(Relationships relmodel, String resident0) {
    // create and return a RelationTree
    return null;
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *How do I create the tree using those inputs* is not a specific problem. Start by writing a `Node` class which holds the `String resident` as well as `List<Node> childNodes` and see where you get from there.

Comment: @lexicore, my question was saying how to create a tree using the relationship of the doubles and their names I apologize for the lack of detail. Couldn't I use a HashMap to associate the two datatypes together? and yes, I have started the node class but I would like to at least have an idea of how the comparison of distances could work in order to determine the hierarchy of my tree structures. Thank you.

Comment: "How to create a tree" is not a specific question. Well, implement it and use it - would you be satisfied with this answer? Because it is as specific as the question is.